# Text file showing up in directory, but can't be opened. Also showing as 'No such file or directory' in Linux

Tags: linux, text, ntfs

I have one text file in one of my computers local storage. Copying it to an external NTFS drive or flash drive causes the file to be seen as empty, or opens up as empty file in text editor on another machine.
On my computer where I have the file, it opens just fine. The strange thing is that if I copy the contents of the file to the LibreOffice document and save it as ODT, same thing happens. The files appear in ls command, but cat shows 'No such file or directory' and LibreOffice opens the odt file as empty.

Is there any chance that the content of the text file contains some illegal character that breaks the whole filesystem? Is there any procedure how can I further inspect this issue?

Comment: Just found out that the corrupted file starts with 'o   ;   ?' or 'ef  bb  bf' in hex. No clue of what that means, but I think it's the thing that makes it corrupted. If I open the file in text editor and then save it with seemingly identical filename, I get two files with seemingly identcal name. After performing 'ls' and 'printf '%s\n' * | od -t x1 -a', I could see stated difference

Comment: Apparently the code is BOM sequence. But I don't understand it is at the start of the filename.